# How to change the title of the system generated search item in the osx help menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight, nsstoryboard

I am implementing my own language handling to be able to switch language of my OSX-application at runtime without restarting.

All menus have been changed so far, my own using tags and the system generated ones I removed (special characters and dictation).

So what is left is the search menu under the help menu. Can this be changed.

As far as i can see it is not a menu item and does not appear show up in the fast enumeration of items.

[image]